# CSS | importing sprites incorrect relative path

Tags: html, css, web, sprite, relative-path

I am trying to use CSS to import my sprites and I have done it 100 times before but this one time it doesn't seem to be working. I am using relative paths too get the image from within my CSS file.

My file structure looks like so:

```
Root 
|
| Index.html
|
|____Content
     |____css
     | main.css
     |
     |____images
     | tips.png
```

The CSS I am using to try and get the items out of the file is as follows

```
//tips icons
.sprite-tips{
    background: url("../images/tips.png") no-repeat;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
}
.tips-tick {
    background-position: 0 0;
}
.tips-cross {
    background-position: -30px 0;
}
```

This is how I am trying to apply it :

```
<div class="sprite-tips tips-tick"></div>
```

This code is copied from one of my other working projects and it is not working, any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure the image file is there and has the same exact path and name? No big/small letters difference?

Comment: yeah all spelling is correct and it is in the project :)

Comment: Try checking this element with browser (ex. Chrome) (Inpsect this element or something like this). Maybe it does load, but is away from div. You will have there informations about errors with loading - just to be sure.

Comment: @deem that was the first thing I did, it sets the sizing from the sprite-tips class but jsut doesnt appear to do anythign with the second class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue by using the following piece of code, although could someone please explain why this fixed it

```
  background: url("/Content/images/tips.png") no-repeat;
```

Comment: Seems like whatever fixed the problem was the first slash (`/`) before the "Content". I doubt that changing ".." for "Content" solved it, indeed adding a new slash on the beginning seemed the solution. Could you please test it replacing "Content" for "..." again to see if it stills working?

Comment: with the `...` where suggested it continues to not load, so peculiar

Comment: Wow, indeed. Then I have no idea about what is going on. Anyway I am glad you solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED ANSWER**

Seems like whatever fixed the problem (as he appointed on his answer) was adding a new slash `(/)`  on the beginning before the `../images`. I doubt that changing ".." for "Content" solved it, since adding a new slash on the beginning seemed the solution.

**OLD (and wrong) ANSWER**

I simulated your folders on my computer and seems that the problem could be with the `.tip-tick` class.
`.tips-tick {
    background-position: 0 0;
}`

Deleting the style, the line-through that appears on developer console (inside the `.sprite-tips` class) disappears. 
Another tricky move could be add the "!important" statement, as shown above:
`.sprite-tips{
    background: url("../images/tips.png") no-repeat !important;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
}`

Let me know if it solved the issue.

Comment: the tips-tick class is correct it is now working however i need clarification on why my previous answer has worked, not 100% sure, I am also trying to avoid !important for syntactical niceness

Comment: Added a comment on your answer.